# Undo Quick Step in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

The custom Quick Steps that you can create in Office 2010 are pretty cool. Although, I'm having trouble finding an "undo" command for them.

For example, I have a Quick Step that moves a selected message to an Archive folder, and marks the message as read. If I performed this Quick Step by accident (or for some other reason), I can't seem to find any way to undo the action. I have to browse to my Archive folder, find the message, and manually move it back.

Is there an "undo" command lurking somewhere?

Comment: Does `CTRL+Z` not undo it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the undo history doesn't log quick steps, this seems like a bug.

I suggest you to post this feedback on the [Office IT Pro forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/officeitpro/threads).

Comment: Posted the bug but no-one is listening http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2009/07/27/introducing-quick-steps.aspx

Comment: Don't do it in the comments of a blog post, it's a high chance they won't read it. The forums or some support section might have more success...